# How to measure with a projection using zoomify?

Tags: openlayers, iiif

i'm trying to measure distance using the [measure example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html).

but the difference is that i'm displaying an image using iiifimage like this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/iiif.html)

I also have a scale line on my map which working well (after setting the projection below on my map).

```
const projection = new Projection({
  code: 'ZOOMIFY',
  units: 'PIXELS',
  metersPerUnit,
  extent: [0, 0, options.size[0], options.size[1]],
  getPointResolution: a => a
});
```

With my measure tool , in order to get the length of my feature i'm doing this :

```
const length = getLength(geom, { projection: map.getView().getProjection() });
```

Unfortunately, my measured distance is totally wrong (compared to my scaleLine and my real image).

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You won't need spherical geometry for your custom projection if it represents true distance, Instead of `getLength(line);` you could use `line.getGeometry().getLength()`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. When the scale line shows 10 mm, geometry.getLength() shows 229.35... getLength(geom) shows 229.096 and getLength(geom,  {projection...}) shows 4254148. I will have a look to scale line source.

Comment: Got it ! I have to do : geom.getLength() *  view.getProjection().getMetersPerUnit();

Comment: mmmm. I now have the same problem with area....